# creating extra excel file using java and POIExcel util if max rows have been exceeded

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel, poi-hssf, hssf

I want to create an excel document with 5 sheets, the data for the sheets is dynamic and I have a maximum row limit.
currently my approach is creating one sheet at a time, and filling it with data. I am checking if max rows have been exceeded, and creating a new excel document.
However this will not wait to check if the other sheets are also exceeding the max row limit before creating the new workbook

My code samples

```
private void populateDetailsSheets(String[] data) throws IOException
   {
      currentRow = getCurrentRow();
      rowCount++;
      short cellNumber = 0;
      for (String value : data)
      {
         POIExcelUtil.createCellWithContent(currentRow,value,cellNumber++).setCellStyle(contentStyle);
      }
      writeToFileOnExhaustingMaxRows();
   }



private void writeToFileOnExhaustingMaxRows() throws IOException
   {
      if(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 2 > Integer.valueOf(SystemProperty.MAX_RECORDS_PER_EXCEL))
      {
         writeToFile();
         rowCount = 0;
         createWorkbook();
         titleStyle = createTitleStyle();
         headerStyle = createHeaderStyle();
         columnHeaderStyle = createColumnHeaderStyle();
         columnHeaderStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
         columnHeaderStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
         columnHeaderStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
         columnHeaderStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
         contentStyle = createCellStyle();
         contentStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
         contentStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
         contentStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
         contentStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
         rowCount = 0;
         createSheet("title sheet");
         populateReportSettingsSheet();

         rowCount =0;
         createSheet(sheetNames[index]);
         setColumnWidth();
         createColumnHeader();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I want to wait till all my 4 sheets have been created and filled before taking care of the extra rows in the first sheet

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to jump to next sheet when the `sheet` one is full. Here the trick.

```
public class JumpToNewSheet {
private static HSSFSheet allocateNewSheet(HSSFWorkbook wb, String sheetName) {
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
    /*You can add style here too or write header here*/
    return sheet;
}
public HSSFWorkbook exportExcel_xls(MyTable table) {
    int cellNumber = 12;
    List<TupleData> tuples = table.getTuples();
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();//Whole book
    HSSFSheet currentSheet = allocateNewSheet(wb, "SHEET");//Initial sheet
    int sheetCounter = 1;//Start at 1 because we already created Initial sheet
    int rowCounter = 0;//1st row in sheet
    for(TupleData t: tuples) {//Loop through data
        if(rowCounter % 65535 == 0) {//Max row reached, build new sheet
            //Increase sheetCounter
            sheetCounter++;
            String new_sheetName = "SHEET_"+sheetCounter;//Name of sheet
            currentSheet = allocateNewSheet(wb, new_sheetName);//Point currentSheet to new sheet
            //Reset rowCounter to 0
            rowCounter = 0;
        }
        Row row = currentSheet.createRow(rowCounter);
        for(int i=0; i <=cellNumber; i++) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
            //Write data.......
            //.............
        }//End inner for loop
        rowCounter++;
    }//End for loop
  }//End exportExcel_xls(MyTable table)
}
```